# SpringBoot OAUTH2 always redirecting to default redirecturi

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

In my SprintBoot OAuth2 application all the endpoints are redirecting to default redirectUri.

Example:

http://localhost:8080/welcome > welcome 
http://localhost:8080/secure-welcome > redirect to github > success > welcome (`Secure Welcome` is expected) 
http://localhost:8080/secure-welcome2 > already authenticated/authorized > welcome (`Secure Welcome 2` is expected)

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/secure-welcome")
    public String secureWelcome() {
        return "Secure Welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/secure-welcome2")
    public String secureWelcome2() {
        return "Secure Welcome 2";
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/**", "/welcome").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/secure**").authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

Properties File:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-id=<client id>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.client-secret=<client secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/welcome
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.github.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
```

POM.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**GitHub app registration:**

[image]

Comment: The `redirect-uri` is not for setting where the application should go once auth is finished, it's where GitHub will send the OAuth 2.0 code for further processing. It should instead point to something like `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github`. Also, would recommend taking a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/login if you haven't already, and first integrate your GitHub with that app.

Comment: You are right. I tried with oauth2/code/github already but due to proxy that was also not working and hence I thought that's the wrong one to use. I realised It on the same day when I came out of VPN. Thanks much dude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There were couple of issues:**

1. There is no issue with the code but GitHub registration.

The RedirectURI must be `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/github`

2. As I was under proxy, the above URI didn't work and I ended up using wrong values.

So in order to make this situation right we need to pass the below VM args accordingly.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost={your proxy}
-Dhttp.proxyPort={your port number}
-Dhttps.proxyHost=your proxy}
-Dhttps.proxyPort={your port number}
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

This made the scenario work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `redirectUri` from `application.properties`, make "manual" redirects like so:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:8080/secure-welcome");
httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
```

Comment: Tried the above.. it goes into loop. because /secure-welcome is again trying to authenticate.